# How to stop months being ordered alphabetically in pandas pivot table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[alphabetically-ordered months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5ScD.png)

How can I stop pandas converting my chronologically-ordered data in a csv into alphabetical order (like in my current plot). This is the code I am using:

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/calendar.csv")

df2 = df.pivot("Month", "Year", "hPM2.5")

ax = sns.heatmap(df2, annot=True, fmt="d")
```

Comment: Make it a datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use ordered [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#object-creation):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month':['January','February','September'],
                   'Year':[2015,2015,2016],
                   'hPM2.5':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
       Month  Year  hPM2.5
0    January  2015       7
1   February  2015       8
2  September  2016       9


cats = ['January','February','March','April','May','June',
        'July','August','September','October','November','December']
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype('category', 
                                  ordered=True,
                                  categories=cats)

df2 = df.pivot("Month", "Year", "hPM2.5")
sns.heatmap(df2, annot=True)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks, this is a way round the problem for me.